# Save data from parse into a string

Tags: ios, string, swift, parse-platform

I want to save data from my parse class into strings. I use the following code actually for retrieving data from my parse class.

```
@IBAction func readAction(sender: UIButton) {

    var tagAutor = ""
    var tagText = ""

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Tags")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("f3AXazT9JO") {
        (tag: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && tag != nil {
            println(tag)

            // tagAutor = tag["username"]
            // tagText = tag["tagtext"]

        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
}
```

In the comments there is what I want to do, in my class called "Tags" there are two cols called "username" and "tagtext" I want to save them in the two string variables "tagAutor" and "tagText". The `println(tag)` is printing out the following:

[image: My console output]

How can I save the objects out of my query into this two string variables?

Comment: Isn't it just `tag.tagText` and `tag.username`?

Comment: What's wrong with the commented code? What are you going to use the for after the function completes?

Comment: No, I have found something here on another question like `tagAutor = tag["username"]` but there I'm getting an error `"Can not assign a value of type 'AnyObject?' to value of type 'String'"`.

Comment: @Wain, the ID will be a variable so that it makes sense. After this method I print out the stuff in a textfield.

Comment: You just have to downcast it to `String`: `tagAutor = tag["username"] as! String`

Comment: There still an error called 'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'String'.

Comment: I am not near my mac so can you try something for me. Try unwrapping the response object first like this: `if let tag = tag as? PFObject { tagAutor = tag["username"] as! String }`.

Comment: I get still the error in the section of `tagAutor=...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell the compiler to convert the `AnyObject` to a `String`:

```
if let author = tag["username"] as String {
    tagAutor = author
}
```

And probably move the definition of `tagAuthor` so you can use I outside the function

Comment: There still an error called `'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'String'.`

Comment: How do you want to deal with optionals? You should probably make `tagAuthor` optional and test it before use. Or you could test and then set when extracting from the tag (does an empty string help you, probably not...)

Comment: In my class `Tags` `username` couldn't be empty, so I just want to save it in a String and go on.

Comment: Check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID342

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't helped me out, it always gives me an error with this `PFObject`.

Comment: Then I guess you need to verify first and set on success